# Load a Javascript progress bar after scrolling down to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, jquery-events, animate.css

I have used jQuery 1.12.2 with animate.css which populates a progress bar successfully. Now I.m trying to only make the progress bar load after I scroll down to it as is currently loads straight away. What's the point in having this awesome feature when it has already been loaded when it is somewhere down the bottom of the page?

I have created a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4azoyq1j/1/). I know the JavaScript is a little messy and can be written in a more cleaner way but please excuse me as I am new to JS and trying to make this work first. Can anyone help?

```
$('#myid').goalProgress({
        goalAmount: 100,
        currentAmount: 75,
        textBefore: 'myid ',
        textAfter: ''
    });
});
```

goalProgress is a whole different class:

```
!function($){
$.fn.extend({
    goalProgress: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            goalAmount: 100,
            currentAmount: 50,
            speed: 1000,
            textBefore: '',
            textAfter: '',
            milestoneNumber: 70,
            milestoneClass: 'almost-full',
            callback: function() {}
        }

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);

            // Collect and sanitize user input
            var goalAmountParsed = parseInt(defaults.goalAmount);
            var currentAmountParsed = parseInt(defaults.currentAmount);

            // Calculate size of the progress bar
            var percentage = (currentAmountParsed / goalAmountParsed) * 100;

            var milestoneNumberClass = (percentage > defaults.milestoneNumber) ? ' ' + defaults.milestoneClass : ''

            // Generate the HTML
            var progressBar = '<div class="progressBar">' + defaults.textBefore + defaults.textAfter + '</div>';

            var progressBarWrapped = '<div class="goalProgress' + milestoneNumberClass + '">' + progressBar + '</div>';

            // Append to the target
            obj.append(progressBarWrapped);

            // Ready
            var rendered = obj.find('div.progressBar');

            // Remove Spaces
            rendered.each(function() {
                $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));
            });

            // Animate!
            rendered.animate({width: percentage +'%'}, defaults.speed, defaults.callback);

            if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback.call(this)
            }
        });
    }
});
}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running this

```
$('#myid').goalProgress({
        goalAmount: 100,
        currentAmount: 75,
        textBefore: 'myid ',
        textAfter: ''
    });
});
```

on `.ready` event

Try to run it on `scroll` event.
For example make an algorithm to check if this `#mydiv` is in your viewport and then trigger this function.

Or use some ready plugin. For example : http://scrollmagic.io/